# Error: parent is null — angular.js

Tags: angularjs, nested, pug

I am getting a `Error: parent is null
.after@angular.js:3448:7` error from angular's forEach iterator. I believe this is coming from a nested ng-repeat.

```
tbody(ng-repeat='comment in comments' ng-include="'../../components/comment.html'")
                include ../../components/comment.jade
                tr.athing(ng-if="comment.kids" ng-include="'../../components/comment.html'", ng-repeat='comment in comment.kids')
                    include ../../components/comment.jade
```

I am attempting to traverse a nested comment structure.

Comment: provide rendered html structure that angular sees. Note that `ng-include` creates a child scope. Not sure it makes sense putting it on a `<tr>`

Comment: the ng-repeat shouldn't be on the `<tbody>` that's not what repeats. I'm making a hackernews clone so my html conforms to theirs.

Comment: Debating between editing and posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using either `ngInclude` *or* jade include, but not both. Also, you can't have child DOM on elements that are using `ngInclude`.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction would be to remove the `ng-include`s from your code, since it seems that you're inlining it anyway in your template? I might be wrong, but that would be my first reaction. `ng-include` uses transclusion, and that can produce some unexpected behavior.

```
tbody(ng-repeat='comment in comments')
    include ../../components/comment.jade
        tr.athing(ng-if="comment.kids" ng-repeat='comment in comment.kids')
            include ../../components/comment.jade
```